# UIScrollView Horizontal Scroll Thumb in the Vertical Track

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiscrollview, uikit

If an insane client had asked for this functionality, I would have told him it was impossible.

Yet here I have your everyday UITableView inside a UIScrollView, setup in Interface Builder. The scroll view has vertical scrolling enabled, but not horizontal. So what the heck is THIS:

[image: Crazy scroll thumb behaviour]

Note the bottom right -- that capsule is the visible scroll thumb in a horizontal orientation. If you scroll the table view up and down, that thumb moves left and right... INSIDE THE VERTICAL SCROLL TRACK. The width of the track is the complete representation of the height of the scroll view's contents; I scroll to the top of the table view, and the thumb moves to the left, so I can just see the right side of that capsule shape.

This has to be some kind of weird bug, right? Any ideas how to shake this loose?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I posted too soon. I deleted the table view in IB and re-created it. The problem went away. Must have been some glitch in Interface Builder.